# flickering scroll bar on side of panel whenever I use a vscrollbar I made

Tags: c#

I have a panel with picture boxes in it and I made a seperate vscrollbar since I dont really like the one that the panel generates when you enable autoscroll, so ive got the scroll bar on the right to work but whenever I use it a scrollbar on the side of the panel starts flickering it only becomes visible when I use the scroll bar I made but it flickers like crazy until I stop moving the vscrollbar, this is the form:
[image] 
and this is what ive got in the code of the scroll bar and the panel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MetroFramework.Forms;
using MetroFramework;

namespace WindowsForm1
{
    public partial class Form2 : MetroForm
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void vScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.VerticalScroll.Visible = false;
            vScrollBar1.Refresh();
            panel1.Refresh();
            panel1.Select();
            panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = 0;
            panel1.AutoScroll = false;
            panel1.VerticalScroll.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void panel1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Invalidate();
        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            VerticalScroll.Enabled = false;
            VerticalScroll.Visible = false;
            AutoScroll = false;
        }
    }
}
```

nothing I do seems to fix the problem

Comment: Have you tried to double buffer your panel?

Comment: yeah but it didnt really change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`AutoScroll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscroll?view=netframework-4.8) property should be set to `true` in order to enable the `Panel` to have a virtual size. The virtual size is the size of the control itself plus the size required to accommodate the child controls. Its automatically calculated and its the size of the [`DisplayRectangle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.displayrectangle?view=netframework-4.8) property. The internal `VScroll` and `HScroll` controls are updated accordingly whenever that size changes.

As a workaround to this problem, you could use an *outer* `Panel` to hide the vertical scroll bar of the *inner* `Panel`, and use the custom `VScrollBar` to set the scroll position. [This](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14801/How-to-skin-scrollbars-for-Panels-in-C) article is an example.

In the designer, drop a new `Panel` to host the main one and edit the code as follows.

```cs
public partial class Form2 : MetroForm
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        pnlOuter.AutoScroll = false; // The new Panel.
        pnlInner.AutoScroll = true;  // The PictureBox controls Panel.
        pnlInner.AutoScrollMargin = new Size(0, 20);

        pnlInner.MouseWheel += (s, e) =>
            vScrollBar1.Value = pnlInner.VerticalScroll.Value;

        pnlOuter.Resize += (s, e) => ResetVScrollBar();

        vScrollBar1.Scroll += (s, e) =>
        {
            pnlInner.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, vScrollBar1.Value);
            pnlInner.VerticalScroll.Value = vScrollBar1.Value;
        };
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ResetVScrollBar();
    }

    private void ResetVScrollBar()
    {
        if (pnlInner.Width == 0 || pnlInner.Height == 0) return;

        pnlInner.SetBounds(0, 0,
            pnlOuter.Width + SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth * 2,
            pnlOuter.Height);

        vScrollBar1.Minimum = pnlInner.VerticalScroll.Minimum;
        vScrollBar1.Maximum = pnlInner.DisplayRectangle.Height;
        vScrollBar1.LargeChange = vScrollBar1.Maximum / vScrollBar1.Height + pnlInner.Height;
        vScrollBar1.SmallChange = 15;
        vScrollBar1.Value = Math.Abs(pnlInner.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
        vScrollBar1.Enabled = pnlInner.Height < vScrollBar1.Maximum;
    }
}
```

[image: SOQ66207174]