# How to get or calculate the sizes of a Panel (including internal ones) to use Custom Scrollbar

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, winforms

Please tell me **how to find out the inner sizes of the panel** (MAX) for scrolling to the right place.

**The number in the screenshot is "randomly generated," and the code and project describe everything.**

[image]

**When getting the coordinates of the last inner element, the resulting value is many times smaller than the value used to get to that element.**

[image]

```
public Form_Main() {
    InitializeComponent();

    flp_Elements.MouseWheel += Flp_Els_MouseWheel;
}

// Scrolling the panel (Flp_Els) with the mouse wheel
private void Flp_Els_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    int step = customScrollBar1.Value -= e.Delta > 0 ? customScrollBar1.SmallStep : -customScrollBar1.SmallStep;
    customScrollBar1.Value = Math.Max(customScrollBar1.Minimum, Math.Min(step, customScrollBar1.Maximum));

    ScrollValue = (int)customScrollBar1.Value;
}

// Scroll the panel (Flp_Els) with the slider on the ScrollBar
private void customScrollBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ScrollValue = customScrollBar1.Value;
}

// Method for overriding the maximum value, when adding elements to the panel
private void flp_Elements_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e) {
    // it managed to scroll beyond (3820) max - it does not move further,
    // but the number of max is greater than above

    // ! HOW TO DETERMINE THE SIZES OF THE PANEL, WHEN IT IS FILLED WITH ELEMENTS AND HIDES THEM

    customScrollBar1.Maximum = flp_Elements.VerticalScroll.Maximum + flp_Elements.VerticalScroll.LargeChange * 8;
    flp_Elements.VerticalScroll.Maximum = customScrollBar1.Maximum;
}

// WITHOUT IT, THE CONTENT OF THE PANEL WOULD NOT MOVE
// Setting panel limits
public int scrollValue = 0;
public int ScrollValue {
    get { return scrollValue; }
    set {
        scrollValue = value;

        // Minimum = 0
        if (scrollValue < 0) scrollValue = 0;

        // Maximum
        if (scrollValue > flp_Elements.VerticalScroll.Maximum)
            scrollValue = flp_Elements.VerticalScroll.Maximum;

        flp_Elements.VerticalScroll.Value = scrollValue;
    }
}
```

}

At the moment: the panel scrolls with ScrollBar, but in order for everything to work properly you need this very number. Tried different options, but they don't work as needed:

1. [First option](https://progi.pro/vichislenie-procenta-prokrutki-scrollbar-visota-scrollbar-bar-7799642)
2. [The second option (described in the Calculations section)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/226381/Scrolling-Panel)

Comment: The size of a ScrollableControl, when it contains child Controls that are positioned outside the DisplayRectangle, is returned by `Control.PreferredSize`. Your min scroll value is always 0, the *real* maximum always considers the `ScrollableControl.ClientSize`, which needs to be subtracted (the dimension related to the Horizontal or Vertical Scrollbar) from the Maximum value.

Comment: Can you write a piece of code that describes what you were trying to say?

Comment: To write a *piece of code*, I'd need to write down an entire ScrollBar Custom Control. The Scrollbar collaborates with the Control that hosts it to send/receive messages related to the Client Area position, resize events, mouse events etc. - You're currently calculating the Scrollbar without considering the ClientSize of the Control that Hosts the Scrollbar (it that's the case, it looks like the Scrollbar is not a child Control of the ScrollableControl). As mentioned, the actual maximum scroll Value is, e.g., `ScrollBar.Maximum (= Control.PreferredSize.Height) - Control.ClientSize.Height`.

Comment: To test this behavior, build a Custom Control inheriting, e.g., the Panel class. Override WndProc and handle `WM_MOUSEHWHEEL`, `WM_VSCROLL` and `WM_HSCROLL` (at least). Print the Values of `VerticalScroll.Value`, `VerticalScroll.Maximum`, `VerticalScroll.Maximum - ClientSize.Height`, `HorizontalScroll.Maximum - ClientSize.Width`, `PreferredSize` and `ClientSize`. So you can see what's what.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66220038/14171304). Replace the `pnlInner` with your `flp_Elements` control.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void flp_Container_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e) {
  // For Vertical Scrolling
  flp_Container.VerticalScroll.Maximum = flp_Container.GetPreferredSize(flp_Container.Size).Height - flp_Container.ClientSize.Height;
  ScrolBar1.Maximum = flp_Container.VerticalScroll.Maximum;

  // For Horizontal Scrolling
  flp_Container.HorizontalScroll.Maximum = flp_Container.GetPreferredSize(flp_Container.Size).Width - flp_Container.ClientSize.Width;
  ScrolBar1.Maximum = flp_Container.HorizontalScroll.Maximum;      
}
```